# Null Object, Sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my repository I try to add a new Stop to the current Trip. The method 'AddStop' is called which will immediately call 'GetTripByName'. It returns the Trip without any problems.

However back in the 'AddStop' method the variable "theTrip" is null, even through while debugging I made sure the object was not returning null. More so when I check if null in the 'AddStop' method it suddenly becomes not null.

I'll then get the error: "Sequence contains no elements" I'm not sure what's going on here. How does it go from null then back to normal, then to null again?

[image: Debug Information]

Comment: When you break on the line *calling* `GetTripByName`, the variable has been declared but it has yet to be given a value, hence it will be `null`. *After* you've returned from `GetTripByName`, the variable will have been given a value.

Comment: A collection can also *not* be `null` while also containing no elements, which would make `Max` fail with the given error, "Sequence contains no elements". In other words, you've gotten back a trip, but it has no stops. You can also see this in the tooltip in your question: "Stops: Count=0". Can you verify what the question is here, because it seems you already have all the details necessary to answer your question.

Comment: You're right, I must of missed that. When trying to add a new stop on a trip that already has stops it works just fine. Next time I'll try to not make the same mistake.

Comment: So, you figured out that the Stops collection inside theTrip was your problem, right?